# AArch64 support in cmake 2.8.11

Tags: linux, cmake, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have installed cmake 2.8.11 and now trying to build llvm with cmake. however I am getting the following build error

```
Scanning dependencies of target LLVMAArch64Utils
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `lib/Target/AArch64/AArch64GenSubtargetInfo.inc', needed by `lib/Target/AArch64/Utils/CMakeFiles/LLVMAArch64Utils.dir/AArch64BaseInfo.cpp.o'.
Stop.
```

Does this mean that cmake does not have support for 64-bit architectire? If so, can someone tell me an easy way to add AArch64 patch to cmake 2.8.11.

Comment: It looks like the `.inc` file is declared as a dependency of that `.cpp` file somehow, but it doesn't know how to handle that `.inc` file.  It has nothing to do with your architecture... it has to do with an incomplete makefile/CMakeLists.txt

Comment: I see. But how can I change the CMakeLists.txt to avoid this error.

Comment: I don't know what your CMakeLists.txt looks like... you should post the contents.  (Make sure you indent 4 spaces so that it gets formatted as code).  You might consider changing the title of the post as well so that others are more likely to read it.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a bug in build script.
See this [LLVM team bug tracker item](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=16625).

> Tim Northover 2013-07-14 15:57:50 CDT Hi Ray,
>
> I think this has been fixed in r182190, which unfortunately just
>   missed the 3.3 release itself. I'm now trying to get it into the minor
>   release we're trying to make.
>
> I'll leave this open, and assigned to me (as a reminder) until that
>   happens.
>
> Thanks for taking the time to report it, and I'm sorry you had to.
>
> Tim.

Comment: For the record, this is the diff, - http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/llvm/trunk/lib/Target/AArch64/Utils/CMakeLists.txt?sortby=rev&r1=174369&r2=182190&pathrev=182190. applying this patch fixes the build error.